# Finding The Value Of Infinite Nested Radicals

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals

The problem is to find the value of,

$\sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{-3+3\sqrt{-4+4\sqrt{...}}}}}$

Even though I have solved the problems which have a definite pattern which repeats itself and we make some substitution to get a quadratic which gives the final answer but I can't think of a way to follow that over here. Can anyone share the approach for this problem?

**Note:** I just came up with this problem (maybe it already exists) but then I wanted to know how could one solve such problems seeing it for the first time. I have verified it for some values and I believe the problem statement is correct. The method of generating this expression has been provided in the comments.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan

Comment: Needs definition.  The obvious one would be the limit of a sequence, starting with $\sqrt{-1}$, then $\sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2}}$, and so on.  These are not real numbers.  Is this what you intend?

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for your response. Actually the above expression should evaluate to a real number because that is how I generated it.

Comment: @Khosrotash thanks for your response. I couldn't find the given expression in the link provided, any other sources?

Comment: I am sharing the method of generating this expression for reference. This expression has been derived as follows: any natural number n can be written as $\sqrt{-n+n(n+1)}$. This way you can keep putting the values of n+1, n+2 and so on... Hence arriving at the given expression. In this case n=1, so, 1=$\sqrt{-1+1(2)}$, substituting the value of 2, 1=$\sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2+2(3)}}$, substituting the values of 3, 4, 5 and so on, we get 1=$\sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{-3+3\sqrt{-4+4\sqrt{-5+5\sqrt{...}}}}}}$.

Comment: @saulspatz Can you suggest any approach for this problem? I have been thinking about it for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

OK.  My reaction based on your explanation in the comments.
Do not say
$$
1 = \sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{-3+3\sqrt{-4+4\sqrt{\dots}}}}}
\tag1$$
Instead say: one solution of the recurrence
$$
a_n^2 = -n+na_{n+1}
\tag2$$
is $a_n =n$.  The reason for saying it this way is that any other solution of the recurrence has just as much claim to be called the "value" of the infinite nested radical as this solution has.

---

Note that given any number $r$, there is a solution $(a_n)$ of the recurrence $(2)$ with $a_1 = r$.

---

Another, more conventional, interpretation of the problem would ask for the limit (if it exists) for the sequence
\begin{align}
a_1 &= \sqrt{-1}
= 0.0000000000 + 1.0000000000 i
\\
a_2 &=\sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2}}
=0.6050003336 + 1.168770894 i
\\
a_3 &= \sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{-3}}}
=0.9306048592 + 0.9306048592 i
\\
&\qquad\vdots
\end{align}
Always taking the principal square root.  Numerically, it seems this converges to $1$.  Can this be proved?

Comment: Thanks for your response :) Actually, it's the second interpretation that I am looking forward to. But then there is something I want to know. Does your first interpretation somehow mean that **this** nested radical can actually have more than one value, or is it just a formal way to state the solution? Now coming to the second part. How does one find the limit? And do we solve the limits separately, one dealing with the fact that the real part converges to 1 and the imaginary part converges to 0?

Comment: By the way I just checked the value of $\sqrt{-1+1\sqrt{-2+2\sqrt{-3+3\sqrt{-4+4\sqrt{-5+5\sqrt{-6+6\sqrt{-7}}}}}}}$ and this is what Wolfram Alpha gives the answer as: 
0.990595496323131608129602187113056817143300587839730453715120097... +
0.190982184495015180077333718720561100674291501644092662000345107... i